# Print values associated with checkboxes in HTML on button click event of JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, html-parsing, javascript-objects

Planning to get the specific ID values from the selection on the HTML page (selection here means checked boxes). Here is my code for a button click event(button will fetch the row numbers or ids):

```
$("a", button).click(function () {
            $('#groups').find('tr').each(function () {
                 var row = $(this);
                 if (row.find('input[type="checkbox"]').is(':checked')) {
                    console.log($(this));
            }
        });
});
```

This returns addtional information on rows + tr tag, however, I just want the ID part of it. Here is sample output I am getting out of above code:

```
[tr#row-12150.row.oddSelected, context: tr#row-12150.row.oddSelected]
[tr#row-12151.row.evenSelected, context: tr#row-12151.row.evenSelected]
```

This means I have selected `12150 and 12151` out of the `#groups` table. How do I just pull the row numbers `12150 and 12151` and not the entire detailed output and I want this to store in an array/(JS array) for multiple row numbers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have the row as per the `.find('tr')`, your should just be able to go:

```
console.log($(this).attr('id')); //this should show the id in your console.
```

so your code becomes:

```
$("a", button).click(function () {
            $('#groups').find('tr').each(function () {
                 var row = $(this);
                 if (row.find('input[type="checkbox"]').is(':checked')) {
                   console.log($(this).attr('id'));
            }
        });
});
```

Then to just get the number you can use:

```
var number = $(this).attr(id).split('-')[1] //assuming it's always row-<<some number>>
```

putting it all together:

```
 $("a", button).click(function () {
                $('#groups').find('tr').each(function () {
                     var row = $(this);
                     if (row.find('input[type="checkbox"]').is(':checked')) {
                       var number = $(this).attr('id').split('-')[1] //assuming it's always row-<<some number>>;
                       console.log(number);
                }
            });
    });
```

To store it in an array:

```
$("a", button).click(function () {
                    var checkedRows = []; //define empty array.
                    var count = 0; //keep a counter to use for the array.
                    $('#groups').find('tr').each(function () {
                         var row = $(this);
                         if (row.find('input[type="checkbox"]').is(':checked')) {
                           var number = $(this).attr('id').split('-')[1];
                           checkedRows[count] = number; //add the number to our array.
                           count++; //increase the count
                    }
                });
        });
```

Comment: @JanR Awesome, I was about the post the same questions, thanks for updating the answer. How do I store the entire result in an array? I want to throw that array via a AJAX call and so, I need to think beyond just printing on the console

Comment: updated for array, once in the array you could do an ajax call after the loop to send it to an api

Comment: One more thing to add to it, in the updated answer "var number = ...." line misses quotes around "id". Other words, id should be in single quote ...just in case if someone else wants to refer this...if that can be updated?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your form and your button have id's first then try this instead:

```
$('#buttonId').click(function(){
  $('#formId input:checked').each(i, e){
    console.log($(e).attr('id'));
  }
});
```